# When i use cocoapods, i got a error: `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

~ » pod --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                    xxx@XXX
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1401:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/XXX/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/specifications/activesupport-6.1.4.1.gemspec, execute` gem env`for more information from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in`block in activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in` block in activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in` block in activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `each' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` activate_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in `activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in` block in activate_bin_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in` activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in` to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/XXX/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec' , execute `gem env` for more information
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1399:in `block in activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in` activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in` activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in` each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1387:in `activate_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1369:in` activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path' from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in` synchronize'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in` '

Somebody help me?

Comment: Hello, Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem! Try to run the following command:

`bundle install`